# JAVA. Create FileOutputStream using URL

Tags: java

I have `URL` object, which I get from `ServletContext#getResource()`, and I want to use this `URL` object to overwrite existing file (using `FileOuputStream`).

*How I can use URL object  to create new `FileOutputStream` object?*

`FileOuputStream(URL.toURI())` - don't help, because scheme component of this URI is 'http', not 'file'

Answer (score 2):

You can't, because a `FileOutputStream` requires a file.  Instead of `getResource()` you could try using `getRealPath()`, which will give you the real on-disk path to the file rather than an opaque URL.

But remember that this will only work if your application is running from an expanded directory structure, not if it's running directly from the WAR file.  If you want a solution that will work in the latter case as well then you'll need to re-think your architecture, maybe storing the files that need to be modified in a different directory, outside the webapp.